# Interfaces with Template methods

Tags: c++, oop, boost, interface

I need to define a Configuration object. I am using `boost::property_tree` for the impl, but I do not want to expose Impl details in my interface, or have to `#include` boost files in my interface. 
The problem is that I would like to use the template method of ptree for getting values,

```
template <typename T>
T get(const std::string key)
```

But this is impossible (?)

```
// Non compilable code (!)
// Interface
class Config {
public:
   template <typename T>
   T get(const std::string& key);
 }

 // Impl
 #include "boost/property_tree.h"

class ConfigImpl : public Config {
public:
   template <typename T>
   T get(const std::string& key) {
      return m_ptree.get(key);
   }

 private:
   boost::ptree m_ptree;
 }
```

One option is to limit the types I can "get", for instance:

```
// Interface
class Config {
public:
   virtual int get(const std::string& key) = 0;
   virtual const char* get(const std::string& key) = 0;
 }

 // Impl
 #include "boost/property_tree.h"

class ConfigImpl : public Config {
public:
   virtual int get(const std::string& key) { return m_ptree.get<int>(key) };
   virtual const char* get(const std::string& key) { return m_ptree.get<const char*>(key); }

 private:
   boost::ptree m_ptree;
 }
```

But this is pretty ugly and not scalable.
Any better options out there?

Comment: Note it is not possible to overload on return type alone, so the second code snippet will not compile either. Limiting seems reasonable to me and having a `get_string()` return a `std::string` to caller which the caller can then convert to another type if necessary.

Comment: Or you can return a `boost::any`...

Comment: You have the call syntax for the getter here `m_ptree.get<int>(key)`, because you have to specify the type of the return value somehow. Can you not use the same technique in your own code?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have virtual function templates - but you coul'd use another *interface technique*, which is called Pimpl idiom.

See [here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/024.htm) and [here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a template and type erasure to achieve this, watch this cppcon video called: practical type erasure. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5PZVuUzP34g)